# How to Treat this Dataset to reduce Outliers

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, outliers

What transformation could I perform to reduce the impact of the outliers? The outliers being the spikes for dates that don't have similar sized spikes around them. The worst being around July-7th 2014-- since there is little to no build up to the size of the spike.

[image]

Comment: What is your data? How did the outliers appear (is it something natural, measurement error, or something else)? Why do you want to reduce their influence?

Comment: The data is the number of times a phrase (in this case "seca") was mentioned across a substantial set of newspapers. I'm considering ones that don't have a consistent build up (or similar sized neighbors) as outliers. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Isn't it for some reason interesting that on some times it appeared more often then in general..? Why would you like to loose this information?

Comment: "Seca" means "drought" in Portuguese, if there's a drought in some part of the country (or world) I'm assuming it's natural that the story gains momentum and is covered more frequently, then as the story loses relevance it is featured less, and less. The sudden spikes (with less gradual build up) don't represent a typical, significant event coverage pattern.

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense: your data is a time-series and you assume that there is overall "pattern" that is observed approximately using the data you have, the spikes are not that important since you are after the "trend" and you would like to smooth your data to make the overall patterns more visible - is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it clearly in the above post. But, yes! Spot on.

Comment: The sudden spikes must be caused by something though surely?